# Play Framework activator 2.3 Upload file does not work

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I am currently using play framework 2.3 - typesafe activator distribution. i have problem when i need to upload a file from browser front-end to play framework backend. i have tested the instruction given in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload

here is my UI code:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.ProjectController.uploadFile, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data"){

    <input type="file" name="picture">

    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>

}
```

here is my routes configuration

POST    /project/upload             @controllers.ProjectController.uploadFile

and here is my java code.

```
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

    @BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = MAX_LENGTH)
     public Result uploadFile() {
      MultipartFormData body2 = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
      FilePart picture = body2.getFile("picture");
      if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType();
        File file = picture.getFile();
        return ok("File uploaded");
      } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return ok("Failed to upload");
      }
    }
```

but when the code reached

```
MultipartFormData body2 = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
```

the value of body2 is always null. it seems like the file is not sent through HTTP post?

in addition, i have also tested using angular upload as in 
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

but it used HttpServletRequest which is not supported by play framework.

would anyone please let me know where the mistake i've made such that the file is not retrieved by play java application?
i would appreciate if there is any other alternatives to fulfill this upload function.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this `@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class, maxLength = MAX_LENGTH)` to `@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.AnyContent.class, maxLength = MAX_LENGTH)`

You set a `BodyParser` as `json` and you uploading images, when your parser detects that uploaded content(`image`) not matches with `json`, it will return `null`. Refer this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaBodyParsers)